# asp.net dynamic data with access

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

can you use ms access as the backend of a asp.net dynamic data project website.  Any links or examples?

Comment: If you're using an MDB as a back end, it's not ACCESS -- it's only JET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought that this should be possible, because .NET generally supports [ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) and thus connecting to a MS Access database. Linq to SQL and the ADO.NET Entity Framework seem to be the most popular data providers for ASP.NET Dynamic Data. However, there seem to be some issues which require modifications to the data providers in order to make them compatible to EF, and Linq 2 Sql supports MS SQL Server only. Because of that, just MS SQL Server and MS SQL Server Compact seem to [support](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=4015016) EF at this moment. There is one last hope, though. According to [this post](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=4015016) on the Microsoft forums, you could implement your own [Entity Framework Provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFSampleProvider) to support Access or ODBC in general.

Comment: There is a thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194528/linq-aspnet-page-against-ms-access