# use Linq with access database

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, ms-access-2007

How to use linq in C# to connect to an access database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check following thread 
[Query Microsoft Access MDB Database using LINQ and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295772/query-microsoft-access-mdb-database-using-linq-and-c)

do check folowing thread too 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1542443.aspx