# query MS access database with LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, database, linq, visual-studio-2008, ms-access-2003

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query Microsoft Access MDB Database using LINQ and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295772/query-microsoft-access-mdb-database-using-linq-and-c)

Im working with MS access database and wanted to know if i could use LINQ to query this database? I read about datasets, but by reading this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/01/26/querying-datasets-introduction-to-linq-to-dataset.aspx 
i see that not much of a database can be accesed through datasets. Can anyone help me as to how i could go bout this? Thanks :)

Comment: Please read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295772/query-microsoft-access-mdb-database-using-linq-and-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately LINQ does not support access database. As work around you could use Ado.net DataSet to pull out the data from your database

```
//create the connection string
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\myDatabase.mdb";

//create the database query
string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

//create an OleDbDataAdapter to execute the query
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);

//create a command builder
OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);

//create a DataTable to hold the query results
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

//fill the DataTable
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
```

Then you can use LINQ to object to do your query (even if I won’t recommend you to use this approach because of the performance are not very good)

```
var results = from myRow in dTable.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1
select myRow;
```

Answer (score 1):

[These](http://www.blsys.net/bls/base/home.html?menu=Developers/dev.aspx?item%5Beq1%5Dlinq2access.aspx?) guys have developed a Linq2Access project.  I have never used it and have no idea of the quality or maturity but it's probably worth checking out.