# Simplest way to fetch and add data to a Access database from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access

I would like to know what is the simplest way to fetch and add data from an Access database using C#?

LINQ doesn't work and the Entity frame doesn't work. Is there a simpler way then having to write a entire OleDbConnection/OleDbCommand/OleDbDataReader?

Comment: question is resolved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295772/query-microsoft-access-mdb-database-using-linq-and-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

have a look at LINQ to ODBC providers or even LINQ to JET/OLEDB provider. Have a look at the following existing solution (although Alinq is known to have a few issues/dodgyness):

- http://www.alinq.org/

Or another option if you are keen then just create your own:

- http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/LINQProviderBasics.aspx